# Is it possible to use を with any intransitive motion verb like 戻る in the same fashion as「駅を出る」?

Tags: particle-を, transitivity

Is it possible to use を with any intransitive motion verb like 戻る in the same fashion as「駅を出る」?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the answers to a similar question [here](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/73467/%E3%82%92%E5%87%BA%E3%82%8B-vs-%E3%81%8B%E3%82%89%E5%87%BA%E3%82%8B-grammar-rule-not-consistent/73468#73468).

The use of を with intransitive motion verbs is a special case which generally fulfils two conditions:

(1) を marks a conceptual point of departure
(2) the verb usually (but not always) involves the movement of animate objects (like people).

Whether other verbs work or not will generally be dependent on the context and whether it aligns with those conditions above. For example, it would sound strange to say 駅を戻る to mean “return to the station” (marking a point of arrival/return), whereas you could say something like 来た道を戻る ([here](https://thesaurus.weblio.jp/content/%E6%9D%A5%E3%81%9F%E9%81%93%E3%82%92%E6%88%BB%E3%82%8B)) because now the を is marking a point of departure.

Comment: 駅を戻る is natural if it means "to go back through/via the station" (i.e. there is an unmentioned destination at the other side of the station).

Comment: Exactly, the context determines whether it is considered a valid point of departure.